# PHP Check if Key Exists in Multidimensional Array and Object Combination then Get Value

Tags: php, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, stdclass

I am querying an API and the response I get is a Multidimensional Object object(stdClass) that also contains arrays. I need to be able to check if the response is an error condition or was successful. If the response is successful I need to return TRUE. If the response was an error, I need to return the error message contained in the response. The response formats for success and error are completely different. The response for an error looks like this:

```
object(stdClass)#837 (3) {
  ["errors"]=> array(1) {
                [0]=> object(stdClass)#838 (2) {
                        ["code"]=>int(324)
                        ["message"]=>string(80) "Duration too long, maximum:30000, actual:37081 (MediaId: snf:840912013693931526)"
                    }
                }
  ["httpstatus"]=>int(400)
  ["rate"]=>NULL
}
```

The response for success looks like this:

```
  object(stdClass)#837 (27) {
  ["created_at"]=> string(30) "Sun Mar 12 13:41:43 +0000 2017"
  ["id"]=> int(840920745073102850)
  ["id_str"]=> string(18) "940920795073102850"
  ["text"]=> string(32) "The Details Posted Here"
  ["truncated"]=> bool(false)
  ["entities"]=> object(stdClass)#838 (5) {
                ["hashtags"]=>
    ........ Way More is in the Response but it does not matter...
```

I have tried changing the response to an array then using isset to establish if it was an error, and if so then get the values of the error details like so:

```
$RESPONSEARRAY = (array) $RESPONSE; 
(isset($RESPONSEARRAY["errors"])) {
$ERRORMSG_CODE= $RESPONSEARRAY['errors'][0]['code'];
$ERRORMSG_MESSAGE = $RESPONSEARRAY['errors'][0]['message'];
$ITWASANERROR = $ERRORMSG_CODE.": ".$ERRORMSG_MESSAGE;
return $ITWASANERROR;
} else {
return true;
}
```

But doing the above give me the following error:

```
Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

Can anyone suggest a way of doing what I am trying to do with the least overhead on the server. Maybe without needing to convert the stdClass object to an array, or if that has to be done, then that's fine, but I just need it to work. Any help someone can offer would be super appreciated.

Comment: `if (isset($object->errors) ) { echo $object->errors[0]->message; }`

Comment: WoW... As easy as that it works.. Thanks so much @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 1):

Below is the correct way to access the object inside the array.

```
$RESPONSEARRAY = (array) $RESPONSE; 
if(isset($RESPONSEARRAY["errors"])) {
   $ERRORMSG_CODE= $RESPONSEARRAY['errors'][0]->code;
   $ERRORMSG_MESSAGE = $RESPONSEARRAY['errors'][0]->message;
   $ITWASANERROR = $ERRORMSG_CODE.": ".$ERRORMSG_MESSAGE;
   return $ITWASANERROR;
} else {
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$RESPONSEARRAY = (array) $RESPONSE;` 
You can get result:

```
  ["errors"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
      ["code"]=>
      int(324)
      ["message"]=>
      string(80) "Duration too long, maximum:30000, actual:37081 (MediaId: snf:8
40912013693931526)"
    }
  }
  ["httpstatus"]=>
  int(400)
```

So `$ERRORMSG_CODE= $RESPONSEARRAY['errors'][0]['code'];` should be `$ERRORMSG_CODE= $RESPONSEARRAY['errors'][0]->code`.
And so on